# update mysql by php in android using json

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

i tried to make an activity that changes mysql database

i made a web server with this code

```
<?php

//error_reporting(0);

require_once('db_config.php');


if($conn){


    $sql = "UPDATE order_detail SET order_status ='completed', WHERE order_id = $ORDER_ID";

        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){

            $response['Result'] =true;
            $response['Message'] = 'Update Order Successfully';

        }else{

            $response['Result'] =false;
            $response['Message'] = 'Unable to take order';

        }

    }else{

    $response['Result'] =false;
    $response['Message'] = 'Some Fields are missing';

    }

}else{

    $response['Result'] =false;
    $response['Message'] = 'Unable to connect database';

}

echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

and this connected with android activity to request the commend, but i dont have idea why is it not working

private void completeOrder() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
                if (Utils.checkConnection(this))
                    new OrderTask().execute();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No Connection Found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


public class OrderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private Boolean result = false;
    private StringBuilder item_ids,item_names;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(SingleContactActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Processing order,Please wait");
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Utils.WS_UPDATE_ORDER);

        List<NameValuePair> mParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order_status","Completed"));
        mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("order_id",ORDER_ID.toString()));


        try {

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(mParams));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            Log.d("Order Preview", res);

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(res);

            result = jsonObj.getBoolean("Result");



        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean res) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(res);

        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();

        if (res) {

            Toast.makeText(SingleContactActivity.this,
                    "Order Submitted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(SingleContactActivity.this,
                    CategoryList.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(SingleContactActivity.this,
                    "Unable to process the order", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: localize the problem. at least the problem side - client or server.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `mysqli_affected_rows()` in your query result because `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)` always return you query result and you always go into `if condition` . you have to count number of affected row.

Also found `syntax error in last else condition`

It may be

```
<?php

//error_reporting(0);

require_once('db_config.php');
if ($conn) {


    $sql = "UPDATE `order_detail` SET `order_status` ='completed', WHERE `order_id` = $ORDER_ID";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($result) > 0) {


        $response['Result'] = true;
        $response['Message'] = 'Update Order Successfully';
    } else {

        $response['Result'] = false;
        $response['Message'] = 'Unable to take order';
    }
} else {

    $response['Result'] = false;
    $response['Message'] = 'Some Fields are missing';
}
```